# Grep method not working in perl

Tags: perl, grep

What is wrong with this `grep` statement? Everything else in the code is working fine, but I'm not getting any output in `@result`.

`$rs_id` gets the value from another file one by one which are `rs548419688`, `rs553613476` and `rs573497853`. When I use the statement `my @result= grep /rs548419688/, @snp;`, I get the correct output. But the code below isn't giving me any output. Could you please identify the error?

```
sub findVariants {
    my ($rs_num) = @_;
    open (my $in_file, '<testSNPs')
        or die "Could not open the file: $!\n";

    my @snp = <$in_file>;
    my @result = grep /$rs_num/, @snp; 
    print @result;
    close $in_file; 
}
```

Comment: I've fixed the formatting of your code. Did you not see how bad it looked? If you are asking a large group of strangers to read and understand your code, then it is polite to make that as easy as possible for them. Please make more effort in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works if `$rs_num` contains the string `rs548419688`. I suspect it actually contains the string `rs548419688␊` (`rs548419688` plus a line feed). When you read from a file, don't forget to use `chomp` to remove the line feed.

Comment: @ubuntu-user: Perhaps you could take the time to explain what the problem was and how you fixed it. Stack Overflow exists as a resource of programming problems along with their solutions. Without more explanation, this question is useless to anyone else who comes across it.

Comment: @Dave Cross, Surely their problem is the one identified in the answer to which they replied, and the solution they used is the one in that same answer.

Comment: @ikegami: Well, we're only guessing that's what fixed his problem. If it was he could, at least, accept the answer :-)

Comment: @Dave Cross, Yes, they should accept the answer, but I disagree about having guessed that it's my answer that fixed their problem seeing as they thanked me.

Comment: @DaveCross my problem was solved by adding 'chomp' statement. ikegami was right

Comment: But there is another problem if you guys can help me in figuring out. This code works fine when $rs_num has atleast one value that matches with the data in file but when $rs_num has all those values none of which gets match to the data in file then it prints other values.

Comment: You've gone from being bad at asking question to being horrible... See [mcve].

Comment: @ubuntu-user: It sounds like you have another question. Please post it separately.

Answer (score 0):

Another case for my standard recommendation:

Whenever you are not sure why a comparison or regex fails, check what your data / your regex actually contains.

```
use Data::Dumper;
local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
print Dumper $rs_num;
print Dumper \@snp;
```

[perldoc Data::Dumper](https://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html)